# Apache serves garbage content

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualbox, mount

I've set up an apache2 (Apache/2.2.16) on a VirtualBox (4.2.6) driven Debian (6.0.6) running on a Mac OS 10.7 host system. I mount a shared folder by fstab with the following configuration:

```
htdocsshare /home/dev/htdocsshare vboxsf defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

The mount works fine, the default user (dev, 1000) has read and write permissions. I run the apache as this user (dev, 1000 – and yes, I know, that has a bad taste, but I don't really think thats the problem here).

I've set up a catchall vhost, with DocumentRoot set to `/home/dev/htdocsshare` (no further settings changed). Apache displays the files and folders in there correct, but when trying to open a file, it serves garbage content. Sometimes it looks like shell script or something like that, as I can recognize messages with variable placeholders.

Opening the files on the mount with vi/vim also works fine. But even if i touch and modify a file within the guest system, apache reads garbage characters. Does anyone have a hint or know what the problem is? Google didn't tell me much, but I don't really know what to search for. Thanks.

**Edit:** I recognized, the content changes from time to time and not reproducible. Here is something it delivers me for an apache error-log (from another server).

[image]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two features the vboxsf may not support: mmap and sendfile. Try adding these to your apache config:

```
EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off
```